# IBM MobileFirst Java Adapter (Hybrid Application) download huge file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to pull a 20MB file from MFP server. So, I wrote the following code in my client application.

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AdapterExample/users/getUpdate",WLResourceRequest.POST);
                                    resourceRequest.send().then(function(result){
                                        Logger("Hello Im here ! : " + result.responseJSON.isSuccessful);
                                    },function(error){
                                        Logger("Im error ! : " + error);
                                    });
```

Unfortunately, it shows the following error in JSON format:

> JSON Result :{"isSuccessful":false,"errors":["**Data size exceeds maximum permitted value of 10Mb."**]}

Is there any data size limitation for Java adapter which **data size cannot more than 10 MB?**

Remarks: Code below is my Java Adapter sample code:

```
@POST
@Path("/getUpdate")
public String getUpdate() throws IOException{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get("/Users/abc/Documents/example.zip");
    byte[] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    obj.put("fileName", path.getFileName().toString());
    obj.put("size", Base64.encodeBase64String(fileData).length());
    return obj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From MobileFirst-perspective, Java adapters impose no such file size limits. I suggest to consider a network issue, such as some vendor your request is going through that imposes this limitation.

Comment: Hi Idan, I tried to call the adapter in Eclipse IDE, the fileData displayed nicely on the screen. But when invoke in my application, it just show the error mentioned above:- Data size exceeds maximum permitted value of 10Mb.

Comment: It seems to be a MFP client restriction. Have you ever solved this?